# what does “GCMRegsistrar.register” do？

Tags: android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

follow this link:https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

At home i can run the gcm demo successfully.
But in the company, it runs failed with ‘authentication failed’
I think there is something wrong with the networks in my workplace(blocked ip or Protocol).

Because i cant find the source code of gcm jars.
So，does anyone know what happened when the client invoke the ‘GCMRegsistrar.register’?
I want to ask our network admin to help me to solve this problem.

I've got the Answer:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/7qPUp0Ym3Ak

Note: 
*If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you'll need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs. It changes IPs frequently. We recommend against using ACLs but if you must use them, take a broad approach such as the method suggested in this support link.*

It is helpful to me.

Comment: Are you trying to run it in emulator ?

Comment: You can find the source codes of the GCMRegistrar in the following directory./android_sdk_path/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/src

Comment: hi,parvin. The source code in the dir is only for the gcm-client.jar.GCMRegistrar invoke the Google api which is close source.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this kind of answers in the offical documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/index.html).

Considering this, `register()` method is the one responsible for

> Initiate messaging registration for the current application.

You should take a look at method description, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#register%28Context,%20java.lang.String...%29).

Comment: The offical document is not enough for me. I want to know where and how the client connects